# Angular 6 Firebase each time upload should add new value (now its only changing the same)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have my upload function which uploads some values to firebase real time database :

```
saveTeam(){
  this.db.object(`projects/${this.auth.userId}/teams/${this.team.name}`).set(this.team)
}
```

It creates in DB like this :

> > Projects/UserID/Teams/TeamNamen {
>
> name: string; empName: string;
>
> }

**I want that I could add as many empNames as I want. How to achieve it ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on what the meaning of the collection of `empNames`.

If you just want a list of the names, in the order in which you added them, you can use Firebase's `push()` function:

```
var teamRef = firebase.database().ref(`projects/${this.auth.userId}/teams/${this.team.name}`);
teamRef.child('empNames').push(newEmpName);
```

This creates a list like this:

```
"empNames": {
  "-LKJDSF2398y2uhd": "Name 1",
  "-LMdswein2rasASD": "Name 2",
  "-LO123dsi2r3AD1s": "Name 3"
}
```

However if each `empName` value can be in the team only once, it's really a mathematical set, instead of a list. In that case you'd use a different structure in Firebase:

```
"empNames": {
  "Name 1": true,
  "Name 2": true,
  "Name 3": true
}
```

In this collection each name is guaranteed to be unique. You create it with:

```
teamRef.child("empNames").child(newEmpName).set(true);
```

Comment: It all works fine ! I would also like to know how to get these employees if u can !